# How to override read-only slot of cl-defstruct?

Tags: cl, defstruct

I'm dealing with a third-party package that uses Structures - `cl-defstruct`s.

One of the slots is `:read-only t`. I need to override that. I need to find a way to change the value in that slot and then pass the structure to a function, essentially "deceiving" that function.

Let's say I have:

```
(cl-defstruct (toy (:constructor toy-create)
                   (:copier nil))
    (color nil :read-only t))
```

Somewhere within that third-party package, it creates an instance of `toy`, e.g.:

```
(setq stupid-toy (toy-create :color 'red))
```

Now, let's say I need to change `:color` to `'green` and pass this "new object" into some function.

I'd try overriding slot-accessor function - `toy-color`, right before calling that function:

```
(cl-labels ((toy-color (x) 'green)) ;; now, whatever within (break-it) asks for toy's color, it should be 'green, right?
   (funcall 'break-it stupid-toy)))
```

It seems that doesn't work. My fake `toy-color` fn doesn't get called. Maybe because `:color` is read-only?

What are my options here? I cannot use `copy-toy` because copier-fn is disabled (see above)
Can I create a new struct type that inherits from `toy` through `:include` option, but `:color` no longer read-only?
How do I create/clone a new struct from the old one?
Remember, in my example, the struct has only one slot; the real struct type that I'm dealing with has over dozen of slots.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. I dug into code and tried learning how oset works. Usually, to set a slot value you'd call it like this: `(oset stupid-toy color 'green)`, but in my case it wouldn't work, since the slot is read-only, it would complain.

Turns out, oset internally calls eieio-oset, reading its source, revealed that it's possible to set the value bypassing validation:

```
(let*  ((class (eieio--object-class stupid-toy)
        (idx (or (eieio--slot-name-index class 'color)
                (eieio--class-slot-name-index class 'color')))))
    (aset stupid-toy idx 'green))
```

You need to figure out the index of the slot, and then you can set the value with aset. A bit tricky, yes, but can be done.

**Update**: [Turns out](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/ueeut9/elisp_structs_readonly_slot_dilemma/) there's much better and more straightforward way:

```
(setf (cl-struct-slot-value 'toy 'color stupid-toy) 'green)
```